# Convert 8.34.208.0/20 to xx.xx.xx.*

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Is it possible to convert an IP address in the format 8.34.208.0/20 to something in the format like this: xx.xx.xx.*?

If yes how can I do this? Is there some kind of online tool to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, since a /20 isn't on an 8-bit boundary this notation won't work, which immediately shows why it isn't useful to use wildcards to represent CIDR-blocks this way.

Comment: He could build a list of 2^^4 (ie 16) 24 bit blocks though... I'm not sure if it helps

Answer (score -1):

I think the tool you're looking for is a "subnet calculator."  You can plug that phrase into any search engine and find a ton of them online.  Their interfaces vary but you can enter your IP address and either the slash notation (/20) or subnet mask into the calculator and it will give you the subnet ID, the broadcast IP and the range of IP addresses that are usable, as well as other details like the total number of hosts, etc.  As has been pointed out, the IP range  won't fit neatly into the x.x.x.* format unless it's a /24.